Range selection
I'm trying to select a range at the end of a script (the idea is to be able to copy/paste the selected range with Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V in another app)
I've put apart the extract of the code of my script. (everything is working well with the beginiing of my script).
There is no error message in the console log but nothing happen. The selected cell/range is still the same than before launching script.
Could you help me please?
function rangeSelection() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var selectrange = sh.getRange('A1:D4');

  sh.setActiveRange(selectrange);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

 }

I was expecting to get the range A1:D4 selected

About but nothing happen. The selected cell/range is still the same than before launching script., when I tested your showing script, it seems that cells "A1:D4" are selected. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? For example, do you want to select cells different from "A1:D4"?

If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to take the values from the selected cells, remove them from where they are, and paste them somewhere else, correct?
function rangeSelection() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var selectrange = sh.getRange('A1:D4');
  var data = selectrange.getValues();  //you indicated the range, but you need to then get the values from that range
  selectrange.clearContents(); //this will remove the values from the selected range

  sh.setActiveRange(selectrange);  //not sure what you're trying with this

  var pasteRange = sh.getRange(/*add your new range here*/);
  pasteRange.setValues(data);  //this will paste the values back into the new pasteRange

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

 }


Hello @Andrew, I'm only trying to select a range like I will do with the mouse (it's why I've try to use setActiveRange). I don't want the values to be erased or change. Just the selection

@SébastienChevin I think I'm not understanding what you are trying to do then.  You mentioned Ctrl-X / Ctrl-V, so I assumed you were trying to cut (Ctrl-X) the values from A1:D4, and paste (Ctrl-V) them somewhere else.

I've mentionned Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V to explain why I want to select that cells but it's outside what I want to do with the script. With my code, I want to select/ to highlight a range of cells (like I will do with my mouse in drag'and'dropping from a cell to another cell ) to get a rectangle from A1 to D4 cell
